# How to change parens color?

Tags: faces

How to exclusively change color of *pairs* (`)}]"'`..)? As of now their face is *default*.

Comment: Put point on the character you want to explore and call `M-x` `describe-char` `<RET>`.

Comment: @Tobias It only shows face of highlighted (matched) parenthesis (smartparens) which overwrites original (fundamental) face.

Comment: Switch off smartparens.

Comment: @Tobias Shows "default". Does (separate) paren face exists?

Comment: "Default" appears to be the answer to the question as written.  If you actually wanted to ask something else (eg, "how do I change the face of parentheses?"), please edit your original post.

Comment: Note, that there is a bunch of modes out there colorizing matching parens. One example is [rainbow delimiters](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters). It is available through `package-list-packages`.

Comment: `font-lock-add-keywords` ?

Comment: See here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DimParentheses